# Genymotion hangs while starting

Tags: 15.10, genymotion

I am running Ubuntu 15.10. I am using Genymotion version 2.6.0. When I open Genymotion it hangs on the splash screen and shows no progress. Sometimes it stops at user authentication or Loading plugins.

[image: Genymotion screen shot]

Note : Ubuntu works fine, only Genymotion stalls.

**Update 1:** Nothing is changed when launching from terminal. Genymotion hangs at Loading plugins screen. No error is thrown.

[image: launching Genymotion from terminal]

**Update 2:** The Genymotion log for the last occurrence is as follows.

```
Feb 21 06:43:24 [Genymotion] [Debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Warning] ****  STARTING GENYMOTION  ****
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Warning] Genymotion Version: Genymotion 2.6.0
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [LaunchpadApp] Started with ("/home/kolappan/Tweak & Soft/genymotion/genymotion")
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Requesting:  "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/"
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] Getting currently authenticated user from  local cache
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] HTTP Status: 0
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] HTTP Content: ""
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Reply error: "Host
cloud.genymotion.com not found" ( 3 )
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] last error msg: "Network error"
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Error] Network error while retrieving JSON content:  3
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Error] [getGenymotionLastVersion] Bad request: "/launchpad/last_version/linux/x64/"
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Error] Unable to get last Genymotion version number from server:  3
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [login] Trying to authenticate  "kols.accounts@outlook.com"
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] Trying to logout user
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Requesting:  "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/login/"
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] HTTP Status: 0
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] HTTP Content: ""
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] Reply error: "Host cloud.genymotion.com not found" ( 3 )
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [doRequest] last error msg: "Network error"
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Error] [login] Login process result: 3
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] Loading "vboxmanage" plugin
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] Plugin "vboxmanage" loaded
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] Chipset: "AuthenticAMD"
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] CPUID 0x80000001 (AMD): ECX= "1d4037ff"
 Feb 21 06:43:25 [Genymotion] [Debug] [VBoxManageCore] Path: "VBoxManage"
 Feb 21 06:43:26 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostinfo")
returns 0
 Feb 21 06:43:26 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online physical CPU number: 4
 Feb 21 06:43:26 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Online virtual CPU number: 4
 Feb 21 06:43:26 [Genymotion] [Debug] CPU number is  8 - Fix max number to 8
 Feb 21 06:43:26 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max CPU number: 8
 Feb 21 06:43:26 [Genymotion] [Debug] [System properties] Max memory size:
3393
 Feb 21 06:43:26 [Genymotion] [Debug] [findHostOnlyInterface] Looking for compatible host-only interface
 Feb 21 06:43:27 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") returns 0
 Feb 21 06:43:27 [Genymotion] [Debug] [findHostOnlyInterface] Checking "vboxnet0" interface status ( "192.168.56.1" )
 Feb 21 06:43:27 [Genymotion] [Warning] [findHostOnlyInterface] Interface is down
 Feb 21 06:43:27 [Genymotion] [Debug] [deleteHostOnlyInterface] Deleting "vboxnet0" host-only interface
 Feb 21 06:43:27 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "remove", "vboxnet0") returns 0
 Feb 21 06:43:27 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "dhcpservers") returns 0
 Feb 21 06:43:28 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("hostonlyif", "ipconfig", "vboxnet0", "--ip", "192.168.56.1", "--netmask", "255.255.255.0") returns 0
 Feb 21 06:43:28 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("dhcpserver", "remove", "--ifname", "vboxnet0") returns 0
 Feb 21 06:43:28 [Genymotion] [Debug] VBoxManage ("dhcpserver", "add", "--ifname", "vboxnet0", "--ip", "192.168.56.100", "--netmask", "255.255.255.0", "--lowerip", "192.168.56.101", "--upperip", "192.168.56.254", "--enable") returns 0
 Feb 21 06:43:28 [Genymotion] [Debug] [createHostOnlyInterface] DHCP server created with success
```

You can download the log files from here :

- [Genymotion Log](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5828F93E1FF9E1F8!50372&authkey=!AHhVRrF8jDWLeok&ithint=file%2Clog)
- [Genymotion-shell log](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5828F93E1FF9E1F8!50373&authkey=!AKaZqFN3HOnLwJA&ithint=file%2Clog)

Comment: Try launching it from the terminal or enable "Launch with terminal" option on the launcher and edit the question with the last few lines shown in the terminal after the hang.

Comment: @user4901968 No error is thrown. It's output is "logging activities to the file". That's all. I have updated my question to answer your comments. Look through it.

Comment: Update the question with the contents of /home/kolappan/.Genymobile/genymobile.log

Comment: @user4901968 Added log file contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can try my answer to my own query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560437/genymotion-stuck-on-splash-screen/35562090#35562090)

The problem was that I wasn't deleting the configuration file. Make sure you do that.
Source: Genymotion FAQ

Details: The problem was I wasn't removing the configuration file in `$HOME/.config/Genymobile`. You also need to remove `$HOME/.Genymobile` folder in your home directory, and yes, the complete installation, normally in the `opt/genymobile` folder, or wherever you installed it.

Comment: Your answer fixed the problem. Also post the details from your Stackoverflow answer (location of config files, etc). Once you do that I'll upvote and accept your answer. And thanks a lot.

Comment: Updated, though I don't believe rewriting almost the same thing here should have been done. Glad I could help you! :)

Comment: Relevant to Windows 10 as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I fixed it by removing the configuration as @Akash Aggarwal said, but trying to login again returns `Unkown gerneric error`, I solve it by starting `Virtual Box` Preferences -> Network - > host-only networks -> Edit Virtual Host-Only Ethernet Adapter -> DHCP Server -> uncheck Enable server.
This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, delete the `.Genymobile` folder from your `home` directory and it can run normally. Also if you want not delete your android device before, just do something like this :

- backup that folder (or rename it, eg. `.Genymobile_Lawas`)
- open the Application (let the application create a new `.Genymobile` folder)
- move the folders named `templates`, `deployed`, and `vdi` from your backup folder to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Genymotion.conf.lock and relaunch. Fixed same error but I was using Antergos Linux.

Comment: If it's not about Ubuntu, it doesn't belong on AskUbuntu.